# Поиск в соотношении many to many

Tags: sql, python, orm, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Есть две таблицы - таблица (музыкальных) инструментов и таблица нот. Они соотносятся как many to many. Связующая таблица - `instrument_sheet`.

Пример:

```
Sheet(id=1, name='Произведение 1')
Sheet(id=2, name='Произведение 2')
Instrument(id=1, name='скрипка')
Instrument(id=2, name='виолончель')
Instrument(id=3, name='фортепиано') 
instrument_sheet(sheet_id=1, instrument_id=1)
instrument_sheet(sheet_id=1, instrument_id=2)
instrument_sheet(sheet_id=2, instrument_id=2)
instrument_sheet(sheet_id=2, instrument_id=3)
```

В итоге - в нотах первого произведения участвуют скрипка и виолончель, а второго - виолончель и фортепиано.

```
instrument_sheet_association = db.Table('instrument_sheet',
    db.Column('instrument_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('instrument.id')),
    db.Column('sheet_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('sheet.id'))
    )

class Instrument(db.Model):
u'''
Инструменты
'''
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(120), index = True)

class Sheet(db.Model):
u'''
Произведения
'''
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(120), index = True)
    instruments = db.relationship('Instrument',
        secondary=instrument_sheet_association,
        backref=db.backref('sheets', lazy='dynamic'))
```

Необходимо найти все ноты, у которых определенный набор инструментов.

Пока планирую обработать запрос питоном:

```
instrument_names = ['скрипка', 'виолончель']
sheets = Sheet.query.join(Sheet.instruments).filter(\
    Instrument.name.in_(instrument_names)).all()
filtered_sheets = []
instrument_set = set(instrument_names)
for sheet in sheets:
    instruments = set([instrument.name\
        for instrument in sheet.instruments])
    if instruments == instrument_set:
        filtered_sheets.append(sheet)
return filtered_sheets
```

Подскажите, как правильно стоит решать такую проблему?

**Обновление**

`orietdb` написан на java. Не хочется тащить яву в проект. Плюс задача довольно обыденная. Самый, наверное, избитый пример - это пользователи и роли. У каждого пользователя может быть несколько ролей. Требуется найти всех пользователей с ролями = 'менеджер' и 'редактор' например. Думаю, что для этой задачи мне поможет оператор having. Осталось это только попробовать и переписать на sqlalchemy. Как будет время, я это сделаю и выложу сюда результат.

Comment: Для действительно правильного решения рекомендую использовать графовую базу данных. Советую orientdb, она попроще.

Answer (score 3):

Вы в комментраиях верно подметили, поможет having.

Сджойнить ноты с произведениями и выборкой нужных инструментов, вывести призведения с группировкой и фильтрацией having "кол-во инструментов в выборке"

Запрос на вашей базе без изменений скорее всего не отработает, но даст понимание что к чему.

```
with t as (
  select id from instrument where insrument in ('виолончель', 'фортепиано')
)
select sheet.id, sheet.name
from instrument_sheet
join sheet on sheet.id = instrument_sheet.cheet_id
join t on t.id = instrument_sheet.instrument_id
group by sheet.id, sheet.name
having count(*) = (select count(*) from t)
```

Answer (score 0):

Предыдущий вариант давал выборку произведений, в которых используются как минимум указанные инструменты, т.е. в выборку попадали и произведения, в которых испльзуются все указанные + еще какие-нибудь инструменты, посему, исправляюсь.

Можно зделать выборку произведений из уже полученных прошлым примером с проверкой соответствия кол-ва используемых инструментов с кол-вом инструментов фильтра.

```
with t as (
  select id from instrument where name in ('виолончель', 'фортепиано')
)

select sheet.id, sheet.name
from instrument_sheet
join sheet on sheet.id = instrument_sheet.sheet_id
where sheet_id in (
  select sheet_id
  from instrument_sheet
  join t on t.id = instrument_sheet.instrument_id
  group by sheet_id
  having count(*) = (select count(*) from t)
)
group by sheet.id, sheet.name
having count(*) = (select count(*) from t)
```

Answer (score 0):

столкнулся с похожей задачей в Excel, реализовал очень просто, с помощью SQL запроса внутри книги. Приведу пример, может кому то пригодится.
Есть два листа, на одном таблица с данными (три столбца: Город, приоритет, Конкурент) на втором листе (два столбца: ID, city) общий столбец у них "Город", он же "city", по нему и будет производится сцепка значений при выборке.
Собственно сам код VBA - "

```
Sub SQL()

Dim varConn As String
Dim varSQL As String

varConn = "ODBC;DSN=Excel Files;DBQ=" & ActiveWorkbook.FullName _
                            & ";DefaultDir=" & ActiveWorkbook.Path _
                            & ";DriverId=1045;FIL=excel 12.0;MaxBufferSize=2048;PageTimeout=5;"  'формирование подключения к источнику

varSQL = "SELECT `Лист1$`.Конкурент, `Лист3$`.node_ID, `Лист3$`.city FROM `Лист1$` `Лист1$`, `Лист3$` `Лист3$` WHERE `Лист1$`.Город = `Лист3$`.city"     'команда SQL запроса

With Sheets("Лист3").QueryTables.Add(Connection:=varConn, Destination:=Sheets("Лист3").Range("E1"))    'выгрузка результата запроса на лист
    .CommandText = varSQL
    .Name = "Query-39008"
    .FieldNames = True
    .RowNumbers = False
    .PreserveFormatting = False
    .SaveData = False
    .RefreshStyle = xlOverwriteCells
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With
End Sub
```

"